# scikit-geometry does not work due to GMP version incompatibility

Tags: python, macos, gmp

I am trying to run scikit-geometry (Python 3, Mac OSX, version 10.15) but get an error message due to GMP version incompatibility:

> Incompatible library version: _skgeom.cpython-38-darwin.so requires
> version 15.0.0 or later, but libgmp.10.dylib provides version 14.0.0

This did not help, as the libraries seem to be up to date:

```
conda install -c anaconda gmp
```

Nor did the alternatives using brew:

```
brew upgrade gmp
```

and

```
brew reinstall shellcheck
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've been trying to build it from the repository but having trouble finding the CGAL includes.